# Dynamic SQL and AO AG - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, availability-groups, dynamic-sql

I have 3 servers with an SQL Server instance (S1\PROD, S1\PROD, S3\PROD) in my cluster and I have a couple of DBs hosted on these with AG AO. I have a lot of DBs and they have 2 replicas (1 primary and 1 secondary) and each DB is in a different AG, so for example Database1 is primary on S1\PROD and secondary on S2\PROD in AG1, Database2 is primary on S2\PROD and secondary on S3\PROD in AG2, Database3 is primary on S3\PROD and secondary on S1\PROD in AG3, etc.

I need to generate some dynamic scripts for those DBs which are primary (NOT secondary) on S1\PROD, however, I cannot find anything related to how this can be achieved with this setup.

For example I need to generate the below, for each primary DB that is on S1\PROD:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG1]
MODIFY REPLICA ON N'S1\PROD' WITH (FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL)
GO
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG1]
MODIFY REPLICA ON N'S2\PROD' WITH (FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL)
GO
```

I managed to get the AG name and the server names of where it is primary and where it is secondary with the below query:

```
WITH AGStatus AS(
SELECT
name as AGname,
replica_server_name,
CASE WHEN  (primary_replica  = replica_server_name) THEN  1
ELSE  '' END AS IsPrimaryServer,
secondary_role_allow_connections_desc AS ReadableSecondary,
[availability_mode]  AS [Synchronous],
failover_mode_desc
FROM master.sys.availability_groups Groups
INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_replicas Replicas ON Groups.group_id = Replicas.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states States ON Groups.group_id = States.group_id
)
 
Select
[AGname],
[Replica_server_name],
[IsPrimaryServer]
FROM AGStatus
ORDER BY
AGname ASC,
IsPrimaryServer DESC;
```

So far I managed the below (the dynamic SQL for printing the statement works, however, I'm not sure whether my IF usage is good and whether I should achieve this in another way):

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    AGname varchar(30),
    Replica_server_name varchar(30),
    IsPrimaryServer int
)

INSERT INTO #temptable
SELECT
name as AGname,
replica_server_name,
CASE WHEN  (primary_replica  = replica_server_name) THEN  1
ELSE  '' END AS IsPrimaryServer
FROM master.sys.availability_groups Groups
INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_replicas Replicas ON Groups.group_id = Replicas.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states States ON Groups.group_id = States.group_id
ORDER BY name


Select
[AGname],
[Replica_server_name],
[IsPrimaryServer]
FROM #temptable
ORDER BY
AGname ASC,
IsPrimaryServer DESC;



DECLARE @currentserver varchar(40) = @@servername

SELECT  
(CASE 
     WHEN (Replica_server_name = @currentserver) 
     THEN  (select 'USE [master]' + char(10) + 'GO' + char(10) + 'ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [' + AGname + ']'  + char(10) +  
       'MODIFY REPLICA ON N''' + Replica_server_name + ''' WITH (FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL)'  + char(10) + 'GO' 
from #temptable
WHERE IsprimaryServer = 1
UNION
 select 'USE [master]' + char(10) + 'GO' + char(10) + 'ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [' + AGname + ']'  + char(10) +  
       'MODIFY REPLICA ON N''' + Replica_server_name + ''' WITH (FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL)'  + char(10) + 'GO'
from #temptable
WHERE IsprimaryServer = 0)

 END) 
FROM #temptable
WHERE IsPrimaryServer = 1
```

Comment: In your case statement you are mixing datatypes - I would suggest 
CASE (primary_replica  = replica_server_name)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

but you have

CASE WHEN  (primary_replica  = replica_server_name) THEN  1
ELSE  '' END AS IsPrimaryServer

Comment: It still shows 0 with ELSE ''

Comment: Have you tried assigning your string to a variable ?
@sqlstr = 'USE MASTER '+ etc etc

and then running
exec(@sqlstr)